# Is the "Fit camera view to viewport" function accessed via the "Home" hotkey available in the UI somewhere?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, camera, shortcut

I can hit `NumPad 0` to enter camera view, then press `Home` so the camera fills the window. But I haven't been able to find this functionality anywhere in the UI.

Can someone tell me where that function can be found in the UI?

Or is it available exclusively via the `Home` hotkey?

Answer (score 1):

Those are two separate functions, and have two separate places in UI menus:

[image]

or, you could find them through space bar search menu. like:

[image]